# janrain engage modal popup window wont close during the onProviderLoginToken event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, janrain

Its been a long strange trip in my travels to get this entire process of authenticating the user using the Janrain client authentication process to work but I finally got it working but....

How do I close the modal popup window after I get the token and then get the users information using $.ajax get method against one of my WebApi controllers?

The whole process works great and I am getting the user profile information I need but after executing my ajax call to my WebApi controller and populating a div tag on my page with the data the modal window is still open with a status under the Facebook logo saying "logging in...."

Im not allowed to post an image yet but if you would like to see the image of the frozen modal you can view it here "http://oi46.tinypic.com/34s1nax.jpg"

Help! Am I missing one last command to close the modal?

Here are some of the code I have in place.

```
(function () {
if (typeof window.janrain !== 'object') window.janrain = {};
window.janrain.settings = {};

janrain.settings.tokenUrl = 'http://localhost:20000/login.html';
janrain.settings.tokenAction = 'event';
janrain.settings.type = 'modal';
janrain.settings.linkClass = 'janrainEngage';


function isReady() { janrain.ready = true; };
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", isReady, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', isReady);
}

var e = document.createElement('script');
e.type = 'text/javascript';
e.id = 'janrainAuthWidget';

if (document.location.protocol === 'https:') {
    e.src = 'https://rpxnow.com/js/lib/idrinkticket/engage.js';
} else {
    e.src = 'http://widget-cdn.rpxnow.com/js/lib/idrinkticket/engage.js';
}

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
})();



function janrainWidgetOnload() {
janrain.events.onProviderLoginStart.addHandler(function () {
    console.log('Login Start!');
});
janrain.events.onProviderLoginComplete.addHandler(function (response) {
    console.log('Login complete!');
    console.log('response.provider = ' + response.provider);
});
janrain.events.onProviderLoginError.addHandler(function (response) {
    console.log('Login Error!');
    console.log('response.err.code = ' + response.err.code);
    console.log('response.err.msg = ' + response.err.msg);
    console.log('response.origin = ' + response.origin);
    console.log('response.state = ' + response.state);
});
janrain.events.onProviderLoginSuccess.addHandler(function (something) {
    console.log('Login Succcess!');
});
janrain.events.onReturnExperienceFound.addHandler(function (response) {
    console.log('Return Experience Found!');
    console.log('response.name = ' + response.name);
    console.log('response.returnProvider = ' + response.returnProvider);
    console.log('response.welcomeName = ' + response.welcomeName);
});
janrain.events.onProviderLoginToken.addHandler(function (response) {
    console.log('Provider Login Token Returned!');
    console.log('response.token = ' + response.token);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:30001/Engage",
        type: "get",
        data: ({ token: response.token }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#results').append(data.Identifier);
            $('#results').append(data.ProviderName);
            $('#results').append(data.DisplayName);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(p3);
        }
    });
});
}



<a class="janrainEngage" href="#">LOGIN</a>
<br /><br />

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to upvote your question at least 10 times!!! Thanks you very much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `janrain.engage.signin.modal.close()` on success or error

Answer (score 1):

Also try this,

```
janrain.events.onProviderLoginComplete.addHandler(function (response) {
    janrain.engage.signin.modal.close();
});
```